Align cylindrically shaped particle with velocity in a particle system
I want to simulated particles that are not spherically symmetric but rather elongated in one direction. This elongated direction should always be aligned with the direction, in which the particle is moving. This alignment should also be preserved after collision with the boundary (which is a sphere).
I attach a sample file. There are two kinds of particles atoms and photons. The cylinders that represent the photons should be aligned with the direction of motion.



I found a possible workaround. If I create a particle system with the simulation node in geometry nodes. I have more control over the parameters and I can achieve what I want. If someone else finds a regular solution with in the ordinary framework of particle system, pls. let me know.
